# Iterate through LUA Table for string match

Tags: scripting, lua, add-on, lua-table

I'm trying to match two tables by string case in sensitive.

Example

```
[6] = 
                {
                    ["itemName"] =     [Ore],
                    ["cleanName"] = [[Iron Ingot]],
                    ["secs"] = 25004,
                    ["gN"] = [[Luminary]],
                    ["buyer"] = [[@Naptha42]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["timestampz"] = 1399514069,
                    ["quantity"] = 100,
                    ["soldAmount"] = 500,
                    ["seller"] = [[@FataI]],
                },
```

I'm trying to move items from the above table format into a new table, or filter them into a list.

```
g = e.cleanName 


for k, v in pairs(savedTable.ALL_ITEMS) do searchTable[k] = v
if g == savedTable.ALL_ITEMS.cleanName then
   table.insert(searchTable, savedTable.ALL_ITEMS)
end
end
```

The problem above is g never = that savedTable.

The table has a few thousand entries and I'm trying to display by search, I believe the best way is to create a new table with the values im looking for?

Or is there a way to use the string.match to iterate through the table and display (print) only these values.

//Update
I have an active search, each time the user enters a letter it will search the table. 
Example. 
    Val1 = "Hello"
    Val2 = "Goodbye" 
    Val3 = "Hi"

While searching and the user enters "H" or "h" I want the results for "hello, hi" to show up but not "goodbye"

```
so with the if g == string.match(savedTable.ALL_ITEMS.cleanName)
```

not sure if that is correct.

//UPDATE for solution of what worked (thanks ESOUI)

```
   local searchForItem = string.lower(g)
    for k, v in ipairs(myTable.ALL_SALES) do
        --        if string.lower(g) == string.lower(v.cleanName) then
        if string.lower(v.cleanName):find(searchForItem) then
            if v.cleanName ~= nil then
                table.insert(searchTable, v)
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: For case insensitive comparison you can do `if string.lower(val1)==string.lower(val2)`. For the rest, it's still very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You have to state clearly what is the relationship between items that you mention in your post. Like where is `savedTable` and `searchTable`, what do they look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ALL_ITEMS` is a table that contains tables then it isn't ever going to have a `cleanName` field directly.

Is that `==` in the loop intended to be against `v`?

Also, if `ALL_ITEMS` is integer indexed you probably want `ipairs` instead of `pairs` to walk the table in order.

Why are you inserting every element into `searchTable` (via `searchTable[k] = v`) and then *also* attempting to insert the matching entries again (via `table.insert`)?

You can use string.match to match `g` against the `cleanName` in your loop if you need to but that isn't going to solve the problem if you aren't comparing what you think you are comparing.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I have got it working... still a long ways to go but your direction helped!